# Javascript transform array using reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to transform an array of objects in form like:

```
const categories = [{
    "category": "Category 1",
    "desc": "Description 1 of the category 1"
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 1",
    "desc": "Description 2 of the category 1"
  }, {
    "category": "Category 2",
    "desc": "Description 1 of the category 2"
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 2",
    "desc": "Description 2 of the category 2"
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 3",
    "desc": "Description 1 of the category 3"
  }, {
    "category": "Category 3",
    "desc": "Description 2 of the category 3"
  }
];
```

to the form (desired resultset);

```
[
  {
    "category": "Category 1",
    "desriptionList": [
      {
        "desc": "Description 1 of the category 1"
      },
      {
        "desc": "Description 2 of the category 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 2",
    "desriptionList": [
      {
          "error": "Description 1 of the category 2"
      },
      {
          "error": "Description 2 of the category 2"
      },
    ]
  },
   {
    "category": "Category 3",
    "desriptionList": [
      {
          "error": "Description 1 of the category 3"
      },
      {
          "error": "Description 2 of the category 3"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

using `reduce` method:

```
const result = categories.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return [{
    ...acc,
    'category': item.category,
    'desriptionList': item.desc
  }]
}, [])
```

but it seems I'm using accumulator in a wrong way and on the wrong place because there is a weird output;

```
[{
  0: {
    0: { ... },
    category: "Category 3",
    desriptionList: "Description 1 of the category 3"
  },
  category: "Category 3",
  desriptionList: "Description 2 of the category 3"
}]
```

[Codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/cwebster750/yLvnw2fh/12/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to use to group the `desc` to categories, you'll to use an object as the accumulator. On each iteration, spread the accumulator (`acc`) into a new object, and add the current `category`.

To create or update the category's object, add the `category`, and spread previous instance of the category (`undefined` is ignored), add the `desriptionList`, and spread the previous `desriptionList` (or a fallback if none), and add the current `desc` item.

Convert to an array using `Object.values()`.

```js
const categories = [{"category":"Category 1","desc":"Description 1 of the category 1"},{"category":"Category 1","desc":"Description 2 of the category 1"},{"category":"Category 2","desc":"Description 1 of the category 2"},{"category":"Category 2","desc":"Description 2 of the category 2"},{"category":"Category 3","desc":"Description 1 of the category 3"},{"category":"Category 3","desc":"Description 2 of the category 3"}];

const result = Object.values(categories.reduce((acc, { category, desc }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [category]: {
    ...acc[category],
    category,
    desriptionList: [
      ...(acc[category]?.desriptionList || []),
      { desc }
    ]
  }
}), {}))

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to group the categories to a Map, and then convert the Map to an array with `Array.from()`.

```js
const categories = [{"category":"Category 1","desc":"Description 1 of the category 1"},{"category":"Category 1","desc":"Description 2 of the category 1"},{"category":"Category 2","desc":"Description 1 of the category 2"},{"category":"Category 2","desc":"Description 2 of the category 2"},{"category":"Category 3","desc":"Description 1 of the category 3"},{"category":"Category 3","desc":"Description 2 of the category 3"}];

const result = Array.from(
    categories.reduce((acc, { category, desc }) => {
    if (!acc.has(category)) acc.set(category, []); // initialize the category with an empty array

    acc.get(category).push({ desc }) // push current desc into the array

    return acc;
  }, new Map()), 
  ([category, desriptionList]) => ({ category, desriptionList }) // convert to an array
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and use Array.reduce() and Array.findIndex to iterate through each object and decide if its data should be added to an existing object in the accumulator or if a new object should be created and pushed.

```js
const categories=[{category:"Category 1",desc:"Description 1 of the category 1"},{category:"Category 1",desc:"Description 2 of the category 1"},{category:"Category 2",desc:"Description 1 of the category 2"},{category:"Category 2",desc:"Description 2 of the category 2"},{category:"Category 3",desc:"Description 1 of the category 3"},{category:"Category 3",desc:"Description 2 of the category 3"}];

const result = categories.reduce(( acc, cur ) => {
  let idx = acc.findIndex( obj => obj.category === cur.category )
  if( idx > -1 )
  {
    acc[idx].descriptionList.push(cur.desc)
  }
  else
  {
    acc.push( { category: cur.category, descriptionList: [ cur.desc ] } )
  }
  
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "!target.descriptionList.includes(curr)" condition ensures that there are no duplicate desc for each category. Feel free to remove it if you find it unnecessary.

```
const categories = [{
    "category": "Category 1",
    "desc": "Description 1 of the category 1"
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 1",
    "desc": "Description 2 of the category 1"
  }, {
    "category": "Category 2",
    "desc": "Description 1 of the category 2"
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 2",
    "desc": "Description 2 of the category 2"
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 3",
    "desc": "Description 1 of the category 3"
  }, {
    "category": "Category 3",
    "desc": "Description 2 of the category 3"
  }
];

const newArr = categories.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let target = acc.find(element => element.category === curr.category);

    if (target) {
        if (!target.descriptionList.includes(curr)) {
            delete curr.category;
            target.descriptionList.push(curr);
        }
    } else {
        acc.push({
            category: curr.category,
            descriptionList: [{ desc: curr.desc }]
        })
    }

    return acc
}, []);

console.log('newArr: ' + JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

Output

```
newArr: [
  {
    "category": "Category 1",
    "descriptionList": [
      {
        "desc": "Description 1 of the category 1"
      },
      {
        "desc": "Description 2 of the category 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 2",
    "descriptionList": [
      {
        "desc": "Description 1 of the category 2"
      },
      {
        "desc": "Description 2 of the category 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 3",
    "descriptionList": [
      {
        "desc": "Description 1 of the category 3"
      },
      {
        "desc": "Description 2 of the category 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```